Edge ideal of a non-simple graph
A graph $G$ is a triple $(V,E,\varphi)$ where $V$ and $E$ are sets, $\varphi$ is a function with domain $E$ and with range $\mathscr{P}_{\leq2}(V)$ (the set of subsets of $V$ with at most $2$ elements). The elements of $V$ are called the vertices of $G$. The elements of $E$ are called the edges of $G$. Let $e\in E$ and let $\varphi(e)=\{u,v\}$. Then $u$ and $v$ are adjacent vertices, and they are also called vertices of the edge $e$. An edge $l$ with one vertex is called loop. A graph without loops a such that $\varphi$ is injective is said simple.
Let $G$ be a simple graph with $V=\left\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\right\}$. One defines the edge ideal $I(G)$ of $G$ as the ideal of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{K}\left[v_1,\dotsc,v_n\right]$ generated by square-free monomials $v_iv_j$ such that $v_i$ and $v_j$ are adjacent vertices of $G$; where $\mathbb{K}$ is a field.
Question 1: let $G$ be a non simple graph. Is it possible to define the edge ideal of $G$ under this hypothesis?
Assume that the answer to the previous question is "yes, it is"; I expect that $I(G)$ is just a monomial ideal of $\mathbb{K}\left[v_1,\dotsc,v_n\right]$. Let $v=v_1^{a_1}\cdot\dotsc\cdot v_n^{a_n}$ be a generator of $I(G)$, one defines the polarization of $v$ as the square-free monomial
$$
v^{\wp}=\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^{a_i}x_{i,j}.
$$
Thus one associates a polarized ideal $I(G)^{\wp}$ to $I(G)$. Since it is an obvious fact that there is a one-to-one correspondence between simple graphs and square-free monomial ideals, one constructs a polarized simple graph $G^{\wp}$ associated to $G$.
Question 2: are known results about these "polarized" objects?

I have no idea what I am talking about and what these ideals are supposed to capture, but assuming that your graph $G$ has finitely many edges, you could let $I(G)$ be generated by $#\varphi^{-1}({u,v})\cdot uv$ for all vertices $u,v$. In words, the coefficient of $uv$ is the number of edges connecting $u$ and $v$...

I don't know if there are known results or if this kind of ideals are really studied. The point is that for a non-simple graph, the edge ideal is not squarefree. All the articles that I read in my career was related only to simple graphs.

@JonasLinssen By definition, $\sharp\varphi^{-1}({u,v})\cdot uv\in I(G)$ ever, where $G$ is a simple graph!
